# Оператор like не работает в методе

Tags: sql, facade

в Фасаде через StringBuilder пытаюсь сделать метод поиска с помощью лайк

```
public List<MainEntity> getMainView(NameValueEntry<Serializable>... filters) throws  Exception {
        List<MainEntity> answ = null;
        StringBuilder sqlFilter = new StringBuilder("SELECT m FROM MainEntity m where m.id is not null  ");
        Map<String, IndexWrapper<Serializable>> filtersMap = new HashMap<String, IndexWrapper<Serializable>>();
        int i = 0;
        Integer start=1;
        Integer limit=25 ;
        for (NameValueEntry<Serializable> filter : filters) {
            if(filter.getKey().equals("start")){
                start=Integer.parseInt(filter.getValue()+"");
            }else
            if(filter.getKey().equals("limit")){
                limit=Integer.parseInt(filter.getValue()+"");
            }else{
                filtersMap.put(filter.getKey(), new IndexWrapper<Serializable>(++i, filter.getValue()));
            }
        }

        if(filtersMap.containsKey("code")) {
            sqlFilter.append(" and m.nf like '%'|| ?").append(filtersMap.get("code").index).append("||'%'");
        }

        Query q = em.createQuery(sqlFilter.toString()).setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(limit);
        for (IndexWrapper<Serializable> value : filtersMap.values()) {
            q.setParameter(value.index, value.value);
        }
        answ = q.getResultList();
        return answ;
    }
```

мой метод в фасаде

```
if(filtersMap.containsKey("code")) {
            sqlFilter.append(" and m.nf like '%'|| ?").append(filtersMap.get("code").index).append("||'%'");
        }
```

вот таким вот образом я реализовал лайк , вызов метода в рестлете

```
List<MainEntity> list = facade.getMainView(filters.toArray(new NameValueEntry[filters.size()]));
```

кусок кода от рестлета , лайк не работает пытался и с '%' и без '%' но безрезультатно .

```
SELECT m FROM MainEntity m where m.id is not null   and m.nf like '%'||?1||'%'
```

Comment: И при чём здесь `StringBuilder`? Сделайте `System.out.println(sqlFilter.toString())`, посмотрите распечатку и подумайте, что сделали не так.

Comment: я так делал не помогло

Comment: Тогда приведите распечатку `System.out.println(sqlFilter.toString())` здесь

Comment: добавил распечатку

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, но в JPQL нет оператора конкатенации строк `||`. Есть функция `CONCAT(s1, s2, ...)`. Но лично я устанавливал бы параметр таким образом `q.setParameter(value.index, value.value + '%');` А генерация запроса была бы такой `sqlFilter.append(" and m.nf like ?").append(filtersMap.get("code").index);` Что давало бы такой запрос `SELECT m FROM MainEntity m where m.id is not null   and m.nf like ?1`